# csv file is not downloading within for loop

Tags: php, fputcsv

Comparing two multidimensional array and get the result by matching values. How to create and download the csv file for those respective values. I have tried this code below

```
$mycsvfile_result = array();
foreach ($mycsvfile as $arr1)
{
   foreach ($mycsvfile_log as $arr2)
   {  
      if($arr2[2] == $arr1[0])
      {
         $mycsvfile_result[] = array($arr2[2], $arr2[7]);
      } 
   }                    
}
```

tried code 1 for fputcsv

```
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="demo.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
      $data=$mycsvfile_result;
      foreach ( $data as $line ) 
      {
        fputcsv($fp, $line);
      }
    fclose($fp);
exit();
```

tried code 2 for fputcsv

```
$csv = "col1,col2 \n";//Column headers
  foreach ($mycsvfile_result as $record)
  {
    $csv.= $record[0].','.$record[1]."\n"; //Append data to csv
  }
$csv_handler = fopen ('demo.csv','w');
fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
fclose ($csv_handler);
echo 'Data saved to demo.csv';
```

The above code 1 results in

```
id1,email1 id2,email2 id3,email3
```

The above code 2 results in

```
col1,col2 id1,email1 id2,email2 id3,email3 Data saved to demo.csv
```

Comment: `$data = array("{$arr2[2]},{$arr2[7]}",);` WAT!!! Why don't you just build a normal array?

Comment: $data = array("$arr2[2],$arr2[7]",); tried this one too @MarkBaker

Comment: Setting headers everytime you find something is redundant

Comment: I have updated my code above, but still results the same @u_mulder

Comment: Why are you quoting the values your'e building in that array into a single string? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when I pass the array values like this ($result[0],$result[1]) the resulting output is without comas id1 email1 id2 email2 @MarkBaker

Comment: All I'm asking is why you're messing about converting array values  into strings (in an awful way) and then using `$val = explode(",", $line);` inside your loop..... it's an awful lot of faffing about adding overhead and complexity (with more scope for creating errors).... just use a basic array in the first place instead of transmogrifying it several times over and then wondering what's going wrong

Comment: As u said i have updated my code above, but it results the same display the values but not downloading csv file @MarkBaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working in linux machine, I forget to give the folder permission to upload the csv file. After giving folder permission it works like a charm :)